# How to start executable program from terminal?

Tags: command-line, nautilus

I downloaded a program from the internet. I simply took the file from 'Downloads' and put it on my desktop. I can launch the program by double clicking on it. However I cannot figure out how to start this program from the terminal.

I tried the following without luck or any leads:

1. `./ clipgrab-3.4.2.x86_64`
2. `sh clipgrab-3.4.2.x86_64`
3. Typed 'alacarte' into the terminal, in an attempt to find the program of interest to locate name which would allow it to open.
4. Launched program with terminal open to find any hints
5. `nautilus-autorun-software clipgrab-3.4.2.x86_64`

The settings when I right click the program look like this:
[image]

I searched all over 'AskUbuntu' but didn't find the answer. I hope you can shed some light.

Thanks in advance.

Mike

Comment: You have a space between `./` and `clipgrab-3.4.2.x86_64`. It should run if you type `./clipgrab-3.4.2.x86_64` with no spaces.

Comment: @PranavMarathe you are absolutly right!!! It Worked! Thanks!!!! Please paste your comment as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: For future reference, please use `code tags` so we can see what you typed easier. (Text surrounded by the ` character)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a space between `./` and `clipgrab-3.4.2.x86_64`. It should run if you type `./clipgrab-3.4.2.x86_64` with no spaces.